# onclick working fine in api 18 but not on api 8

Tags: java, android, xml, compatibility, onclicklistener

I have an app in which a player activity is initiated by a notification. In the player activity there are two buttons. I have implemented onclick listener on each button but its not working in api 8.

Player.java

```
public class Player extends BaseActivity implements OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayerControl {

private static final String TAG = "AudioPlayer";
Button done , snz;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
String name, alrname;
WebView wv;
RelativeLayout r1;
  public static final String AUDIO_FILE_NAME = "audioFileName";

  private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
  private MediaController mediaController;
  private String audioFile;
  Database info = new Database(Player.this);

  private Handler handler = new Handler();


  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    Resources res = getResources();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.top));

    r1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.addview2);
    r1.addView(adView);

    wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.pl_wv);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/wave.gif");

    done = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_done);
    snz = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_snooze);

    name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("flag");

    audioFile = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/com.pras.ToDo/" + name + ".3gpp");
    Log.e("AUDIO FILE SOURCE ---->", audioFile);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaController = new MediaController(this) {
        @Override
        public void hide() {
            mediaController.show(0);
        }
    };

    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFile);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.e("Sound-->", "stopped");
                //pause();
                wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/back.gif");
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not open file " + audioFile + " for playback.", e);
    }
    done.setClickable(true);
    snz.setClickable(true);

    done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.e("done", "reminder deleted");
            File file = new File(audioFile);
            file.delete();
            info.open();
            info.deleteEntry(name);
            info.deletealr(name);
            info.close();
            finish();   
        }
    });

    snz.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("snooze", "reminder alarm");
            String time = null;
            info.open();
            String key = info.getAlrData(name);
            info.close();
            SharedPreferences sp  = getSharedPreferences("ESP", MODE_PRIVATE);
            int i = sp.getInt("esp_time", 5);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy  hh:mm a");
            try {
                Date k= sdf.parse(key);
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.setTime(k);
                c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, i);
                time = sdf.format(c.getTime());
                time = time.replace(" ", "");
                time = time.replace(":", "");
                time = time.replace("/", "");
                Log.e("New Time---->", time);
                info.open();
                info.addEntry(time);
                info.deleteEntry(name);
                info.close();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Date Parsing", "Date not parsed");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            File from = new File(audioFile);
            File to  = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/com.pras.ToDo/"+ time+".3gpp");
            from.renameTo(to);
            finish();
        }
    });
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
  }

 /* @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //the MediaController will hide after 3 seconds - tap the screen to make it appear again
    mediaController.show();
    return false;
  }*/

  //--MediaPlayerControl methods----------------------------------------------------
  public void start() {
    mediaPlayer.start();
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/wave.gif");
  }

  public void pause() {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/back.gif");
  }

  public int getDuration() {
    return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
  }

  public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
  }

  public void seekTo(int i) {
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
  }

  public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
  }

  public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return 0;
  }

  public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
  }


  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared");
    mediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.ivmc));
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        mediaController.setEnabled(true);
        mediaController.show();
      }
    });
  }

@Override
public int getAudioSessionId() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();
    }

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.e("State", "pause");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e("State", "resume");
}
}
```

NotifierService.java

```
public class NotifierService extends Service {
Calendar c;
Date curdate;
Database info;
String date , time ;
int year, month, day, hour, min;
NotificationManager nm;
Notification mNotification;
Handler handler;
 @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
     super.onStart(intent, startId);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Service running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        handler = new Handler(){

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        };

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() { 
            while(true)
            {
               try {
                   SharedPreferences sp  = getSharedPreferences("SettingSharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String check = sp.getString("settings", "asd");
                    Log.e("CheckBox notifier---->", check);
                    Thread.sleep(60000);
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
                    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                    info = new Database(NotifierService.this);
                    info.open();
                    String data = info.getTimeEntry( day, month , year, hour, min);
                    String res = info.setalr(c);
                    info.close();

                    if(data!= null){
                        Log.e("DATA FROM DB -->", data);
                        SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("TODOSHAREDPREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        if(data.equals(shared.getString("key", "asdf"))){
                            Log.e("Notifier---->", "Notification stopped");
                        }
                        else{
                            Editor editor = shared.edit();
                            editor.putString("key", data);
                            editor.commit();
                            if(check.equals("true")){
                                Log.e("check box notifier--->", "Notification stopped by checkbox");
                            }
                            else{
                                SharedPreferences sd_uri = getSharedPreferences("TONESHDPR", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                String s = sd_uri.getString("tone_set", "Default tone");
                                Uri sound;

                                 if(s.equals("Default tone")){
                                 sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                                 }else{
                                     sound =Uri.parse(s);
                                 }

                                 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                                                .setContentTitle("Voice Reminder")
                                                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                                                                .setContentText("You have Something to do Listen up!")
                                                                .setSound(sound)
                                                                .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                                                                .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
                                                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                                                .setOngoing(true);
                                 Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Player.class);
                                 in.putExtra("flag", data);
                                 PendingIntent pending=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, in ,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                                 mBuilder.setContentIntent(pending);
                                 NotificationManager mNotificationManager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                 mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
                         }
                     }

                 }

                 if(res!= null){
                     Log.e("DATA for Alarm -->", res);
                     SharedPreferences alarm = getSharedPreferences("ToDoALARM", MODE_PRIVATE);
                     if(res.equals(alarm.getString("alrKEY", "asdf"))){
                         Log.e("Notifier---->", "Notification stopped");
                     }
                     else{
                         Editor editor = alarm.edit();
                         editor.putString("alrKEY", res);
                         editor.commit(); 
                         if(check.equals("true")){
                             Log.e("check box notifier--->", "Notification stopped by checkbox");
                         }
                         else{
                             SharedPreferences sd_uri = getSharedPreferences("TONESHDPR", MODE_PRIVATE);
                             String s = sd_uri.getString("tone_set", "Default tone");
                             Uri sound;

                             if(s.equals("Default tone")){
                                 sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                             }else{
                                 sound =Uri.parse(s);
                             }

                             NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                                                .setContentTitle("Voice Reminder Alarm")
                                                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                                                                .setContentText("Listen up the notification you have snoozed earlier !")
                                                                .setSound(sound)
                                                                .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                                                                .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
                                                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                                                .setOngoing(true);
                              Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Player.class);
                              in.putExtra("flag", res);
                              PendingIntent pending=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, in ,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                              mBuilder.setContentIntent(pending);
                              NotificationManager mNotificationManager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                              mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
                         }

                     }
                 }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

            }

                            }
        }).start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;       
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

player.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:weightSum="5"
android:id="@+id/main_audio_view" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_snooze"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/snooze"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" 
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_done"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/done"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/pl_wv"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivmc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/addview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" >
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? post a logcat.

Comment: Feel free to explain what "not working" means for you.

Comment: @Dev there is no error in logcat when i click on button nothing happens

Comment: @laalto not working means that button do not react to onclick event its simply doesn't performs the function written inside the click listener

Comment: do you have a fragment.xml?

Comment: @Dev No there is no fragment.xml

Comment: @Rahul this really confuses me...try using android:onclick in xml ,copy your code inside onclick() and put it inside  public method(View v) ... just to check...

Comment: @Dev not working bro....

Comment: @RahulSharma how are you checking this on api 8 and 18 got two emulators? or in real device?

Comment: @Dev i have api 18 device and api 8 emulator

Answer (score 0):

Try removing, done.setClickable(true); and snz.setClickable(true);

It will make the button focus stay permanent..

Worst case : you can use "setEnabled"..

Comment: nothing happens after removing done.setClickable(true) and snz.setClickable(true) the problem remains as it is:(

Comment: you can try this workaround : in the xml file mention android:onClick="SomeMethodName" and define the method in the class file.. and execute..